# In Eclipse, how do i disable text highlighting with same occurence for Typescript when cursor is inside a word

Tags: eclipse, typescript

[image]

So i'm not talking about text highlighting when a single word is highlighted. My eclipse also highlights other words when the cursor is just in between a word, like you see in the picture. Which is extremely irritating imo.

So i want text highlighting to happen if i highlight a word, but not when my cursor is in the word.

Comment: No it's not possible. You can disable mark occurrences in "Window / Preferences" -> "JavaScript / Editor / Mark Occurences". I have never seen this feature, JDT (Java Plugin) and other plugins works like this. VSCode works like this too.